# Cannot access the getter within POJO class

Tags: android, gson, adapter, pojo

I am trying to access a getter method which is inside a POJO class within my response modal.

```
public class Event implements Parcelable{

    class Name {

        @SerializedName("text")
        @Expose
        public String eventName;

        public String getEventName() {
            return eventName;
        }
    }
.
. some parcelable stuff here
.
}
```

I am trying to access the getEventName method from within my adapter class. my piece of code there goes like this ( cant access the method, geteventname):

```
holder.cardTextView.setText(eventsList.get(position).getEventName());
```

If i define another variable outside of an inner pojo class, i can reach its getter, i can only not reach the one within the pojo class.

*Edit*
I am trying to read a json response like this, the text under name is the one im trying to build the modal for.

```
    "events": [
        {
            "name": {
                "text": "textextextext", 
                "html": "textextextext"
            }, 
            "description": {} 
.
.
.
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON nesting is fun.

`name` is an inner class.  Looks like `description` is also.

`events":[ { "name":{ "text":" text ", "html":"something " }, "description":{ }, ... }]`

In the above, there is an array of `events`.

Every event has a `name`, and every name has a "text" and an "html".
Every event also has a `description`, which has it's own fields.

You are on the right track:

```
public class Event implements Parcelable{

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
public Name name;

@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
public Description description;


public class Name {

    @SerializedName("text")
    @Expose
    public String eventName;

    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }
}

public class Description {

   //whatever fields are in the description object in the json
}

.
. some parcelable stuff here
.
}
```

You would access it like: `holder.cardTextView.setText(eventsList.get(position).name.getEventName());`

If this works you can clean it up by adding custom getters to the event class.

Comment: Sorry for the spam, im trying to get the text string within the name jsonobject under events json array                                                    "events":[  
      {  
         "name":{  
            "text":" text ",
            "html":"something "
         },
         "description":{  },

Comment: Thank you so much edthethird. I added a getter over your changes to the Event class, and called the getEventName method through that. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this `getEventName()` with parentheses  :

```
holder.cardTextView.setText(eventsList.get(position).getEventName());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.cardTextView.setText(eventsList.get(position).getEventName());
```

try this. use parentheses for function call